Timeout parameter in subprocess does not work in chainlit app
I have a script to build a Chainlit UI for my GraphRAG app running in windows. The GraphRAG query runs fine in the terminal, although it takes about 120 seconds (screenshot attached). However, when I run this Chainlit script, the timeout=300 in subprocess.run does not work as expected. Instead, I get a 'can't reach server' error after approximately 60 seconds, even though the result is eventually returned (terminal screenshot also attached). How can I enforce the script to wait until the response is received?
import chainlit as cl
import subprocess
import shlex

@cl.on_chat_start
def start():
    cl.user_session.set("history", [])
    # cl.set_theme(cl.Theme(background="white"))
    # cl.set_header("Duality Expert Chat")


@cl.on_message
async def main(message: cl.Message):
    history = cl.user_session.get("history")

    query = message.content

    cmd = [
        "python", "-m", "graphrag.query",
        "--root", r"C:\Users\Lei Shang\Documents\Projects\LLM_RAG\GraphRAG_ollama_LMStudio_chainlit\graphRag\mistral-large\graphRag-mistral-large",
        "--method", "global",
    ]

    cmd.append(shlex.quote(query))

    try:
        print(cmd)
        result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True, timeout=300)
        print(result)
        output = result.stdout

        # extract content tailing "SUCCESS: Global Search Response:" 
        response = output.split("SUCCESS: Global Search Response:", 1)[-1].strip()

        history.append((query, response))
        cl.user_session.set("history", history)

        await cl.Message(content=response).send()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        error_message = f"An error occurred: {e.stderr}"
        await cl.Message(content=error_message).send()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cl.run()




